# Need to confirm my application is vulnerable for XSS using href of an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

After intercepting response from the server I am replacing href of an anchor tag data to `<script>alert(8007)</script>`, Please find the attached screen shots for clear picture and confirm me if it's vulnerable or not.

Before Inserting XSS script

Start player Start Team

XSS script which inserted

[image]

After inserting XSS script

[image]

Comment: because the script wasn't added to the dom but instead as a value for html attribute, I don't think it's vulnerable

Comment: Please don't attach code as pictures. Use the excellent code formatting features of StackOverflow to paste your XML as text instead.

Comment: A URL like so is how you do XSS <a href="javascript:alert(1000)"> heh </a> or <img src="javascript:alert(1)> and through many other things like event handlers etc.

I have no idea of whether your site is vulnerable or not. You need to actually explain how your site works, and how users can enter data. My current guess though is that your site would be.

Comment: Hi James Wakefield thanks for suggestion, I am able to get reflected XSS.